# Different ways of limiting the sequential ordered Stream

Tags: java, performance, java-stream

Since java 11 there are several ways to limit sequential ordered Stream:

1. `Stream.iterate(0, v -> v + 1).limit(size)`
2. `Stream.iterate(0, v -> v < size, v -> v + 1)`
3. `Stream.iterate(0, v -> v + 1).takeWhile(v -> v < size)`
4. ...

What is the best, for example, in terms of performance way to do so?

Comment: 4. `IntStream.range(0, size)`

Answer (score -1):

I made a quick test of generating 1000000 elements. I measured the execution  time 10000 times and took an average:

```java
int tests = 10000;
int size = 1000000;
long [] limit = new long[tests];
for(int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
    long tic = System.nanoTime();
    Stream.iterate(0, v -> v + 1).limit(size).count();
    long toc = System.nanoTime();
    limit[i] = toc - tic;
}

long [] timesIterate1 = new long[tests];
for(int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
    long tic = System.nanoTime();
    Stream.iterate(0, v -> v < size, v -> v + 1).count();
    long toc = System.nanoTime();
    timesIterate1[i] = toc - tic;
}

long [] timesTakeWhile = new long[tests];
for(int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
    long tic = System.nanoTime();
    Stream.iterate(0, v -> v + 1).takeWhile(v -> v < size).count();
    long toc = System.nanoTime();
    timesTakeWhile[i] = toc - tic;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(limit).average().orElseThrow() / 1000 / 1000);
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(timesIterate1).average().orElseThrow() / 1000 / 1000);
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(timesTakeWhile).average().orElseThrow() / 1000 / 1000);
```

The results are:

| Method | Time |
| --- | --- |
| Stream.iterate(0, v -> v + 1).limit(size).count() | 5.98ms |
| Stream.iterate(0, v -> v < size, v -> v + 1).count() | 3.52ms |
| Stream.iterate(0, v -> v + 1).takeWhile(v -> v < size).count() | 8.80ms |

Seems to be that `Stream.iterate(0, v -> v < size, v -> v + 1)` is the fastest way.

I used java 17.

Comment: Note that microbenchmarking in Java is notoriously difficult, and the presented approach has several problems. First of all, since the results of your stream calculations are unused, the entire call can/may be optimized out. Second, even if the result (the count) was used, the implementation would be allowed to optimize the expression if it can calculate the result in advance (probably not the case here with current runtimes, but possible in principle).

Comment: Microbenchmarks should be done with a proper test harness like [JMH](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness) to isolate runs and avoid any optimizations. Iteration is also not the place where you're going to be finding performance improvements in code, the different iteration ways depend more on the type of the stream you're handling than finding the fastest one.